# .htaccess code to redirect visits from I.P address to Domain Name

Tags: .htaccess

I noticed I can access my website "cbdshopy.co.uk" using the I.P address "134.209.16.153" which is causing duplicate content.

I'd like to redirect IP visits to the domain.

This is my current .htaccess which works 100% forcing https & non-www

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I've tried to add the following line to my .htaccess to force IP visits to the domain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^134.209.16.153
```

Like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^134.209.16.153
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But doesn't seem to do the trick.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Your rule didnt work because  you are checking two different host headers `www.example` and `134.209.16.153` . You only need to check the IP host .

Here is the corrected version:

```
#redirect ip to domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^134.209.16.153
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#www to non-www
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
#non ssl to ssl
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing these new redirects.

Comment: The I.P now redirects to the domain. 

But not other URLS found on the I.P i.e https://134.209.16.153/what-is-cbd/

Is there a way to catch all the I.P urls?

Comment: @ClaudioSantos Put your redirect rules at the top of your htaccess  right bellow `RewriteEngine on` line

Comment: Ok, thanks it's working 100% now, just needed to add the WP default .htaccess to the bottom.

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]